# How to use `after_update' callback in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I want to use after_update callback method for a method, which updates the product's stock in shopping cart application. The code in controller is:
ProductsController.rb:

```
  def update
     order = current_order
     @order_item = order.order_items.find(params[:id])
     @order_item.product.save
 end
```

And in ProudctModel:

```
 after_update :remove_stock
 def remove_stock
   puts "this is #{order_items}"
   order_items.collect do |oi|
       puts "this is product id: #{oi.product.id}"

   end
 end
```

However, on running the above the log is as follows:

```
order items product: 1
order items product: 1
order items product: 1
order items product: 1
order items product: 1
order items product: 1
order items product: 1
order items product: 1
order items product: 1
order items product: 1
order items product: 1
order items product: 1
```

Why is this showing so many product_ids, when there is only one product present in order_item?

PS: My associations are as follows:

product has_many order_items

order_items belongs_to order

order has_many order_items

What am I missing ?
Please help.
Thanks inadvance.

Comment: you're printing order items id instead of product id, if I'm not wrong

Comment: Yes sorry about that. But my real question is, why is it looping through so many times? Even when I changed it to product.id, it is print the id as many times as shown in the question. Why so ?

Comment: because you're looping over all the order_items, `order_items.collect do |oi|`

Comment: I checked it. There is only one order_item in order_items.

Comment: check the answer I have posted, can you try that code? and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 after_update :remove_stock
 def remove_stock
   puts "this is product id: #{self.id}"
 end
```

since you're in Product model itself, you have access to the Product object

Comment: This worked. One more doubt. I also what order_item object in the remove_stock method. How to get that?

Comment: you can find the order_items for that product id in model

Comment: How? I used  `product.order_items` , it threw error. I am sorry if I am missing something obvious, but I am new to rails and just learning these methods.

Comment: just write `self.order_items` or `order_items` directly it will work

Comment: The table order_item contains a attribute quantity, which i want to use here in this method. So how to call that specific order_item  associated with the product from the order_items collection?

Comment: I used this to find out the quantity `    order_items.each do |o|
      puts "this #{o.quantity}"
    end` but instead of just printing it once, it is getting printed 3/4 times, every time the page is refreshed.